# Using OpenGL in a regular window (Win32)

Tags: c++, opengl, winapi

I want to use OpenGL in my WndProc but I'm not sure how. I also don't want GL to occupy the whole screen, just a portion of the screen. In the end I basically want to make a drawing win32 app but use OGL instead of GDI. so how can I tell GL to use my control (a panel) 's hdc for drawing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `wglCreateContext`, pass the control's HDC instead of the window. The same thing works on OpenGL and DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wglCreateContext` on any HDC, but you can't mix the drawing with GDI.

Comment: Isn't there a flag you can pass at context creation/pixel format selection that allows GDI interop?